# How to make a custom server run in a cluster

Tags: java, load-balancing, server, failover, helix

I have a custom server listening to jdbc requests a DB Proxy. I would like t to run in a load-balancing/failover environment which provides

- Session Stickiness (My application itself is not distributed and it just preprocesses the query and relays it to the DB).

  High Availability.

  Node Failure Discovery and Recovery.

  Horizontal Scalability

I was looking at Apache Helix, Is that a good candidate. I know this is not a direct question but could be viewed as "How to make servers run in a clustered mode"

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://www.openstack.org/ wich can give you this infrastructure. 
If you're looking for a professional solution you can search for google cloud or amazonws.